# Underscore Templating: Partials or includes

Tags: javascript, templates, backbone.js, underscore.js

I am using [underscore](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/) templating to render html on the client side. I am constructing a news feed which contains different types of new feed items that each require a different template. The thing is they all share the same Comments area at the bottom of each feed item. I would therefore only like to template this once but have it rendered in each of the seperate feeditem templates.

**What is the best way of including comments inside each feed item without duplicating the comments template inside each of the feed item templates?** Should I just run the comments template outside of the main template and append the html after?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be smart to keep the comment template separate, especially considering you should have a model and collection for the comments.  The best idea would be to have each template include something like `<div class="comments-section"></div>`.  Then in your backbone.js view, you could have something like this:

```
Backbone.View.extend({

    ...

    getCommentsEl: function() {
        return this.$('.comments-section');
    },

    addCommentsSection: function() {
        this.getCommentsEl().html(_.template(...));
    }

    ...

});
```